# IComparable interface in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This is a demo of IComparable interface in Powershell

```bsh
class ComparableRect : Rect, System.IComparable {
    ComparableRect([String] $color, [Double] $width, [Double] $height)
        : Base($color, $width, $height) {}

    [Int] CompareTo($rhs) {
        if ($rhs -isnot [ComparableRect]) {
            Throw "NotIcomparable"
        } else {
            return $this.Area() - $rhs.Area()
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this

```bsh
$a = [ComparableRect]::new("Red", 1, 9)
$b = [ComparableRect]::new("Green", 3, 3)
```

> $a -eq $b # => False
>   $a -lt $b # => False
>   $a -gt $b # => False
>   $a -le $b # => True
>   $a -ge $b # => True

I'm not sure if function CompareTo works

here are base classes

```bsh
class Shape {
    [ValidateSet("Red", "Green", "Blue")]
    [String] $Color

    Shape([String] $color) {
        $this.Color = $color
    }

    [Void] ChangeColor($newColor) {
        $this.Color = $newColor
    }

    [String] ToString() {
        return ("Shape [ Color: {0} ]" -f $this.Color)
    }
}

class Rect : Shape {
    [Double] $Width
    [Double] $Height

    Rect([String] $color, [Double] $width, [Double] $height) : Base($color) {
        $this.Width  = $width
        $this.Height = $height
    }

    [Double] Area() {
        return $this.Width * $this.Height
    }
    [String] ToString() {
        return ("Shape [ Color: {0}; Width: {1}; Height: {2} ]" `
             -f $this.Color, $this.Width, $this.Height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` is using the `IEquatable` interface while `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt` and `-ge` use the `IComparable` interface. Is `IEquatable` not set, powershell uses  [reference-equality](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/12/05/powershells-eq-operator-reference-equality-vs-value-equality/). That is the reason why `$a -eq $b # => False` but `$a -ge $b # => True`. I made an example to show the difference between `IEquatable` and `IComparable`:

```
Class CompClass : System.IComparable
{
    [int] $Value
    CompClass([int] $v)
    {
        $this.Value = $v
    }
    [int] CompareTo($that)
    {
        If (-Not($that -is [CompClass])) {
            Throw "Not comparable!!"
        }
        return $this.Value - $that.Value
    }
}

$a = [CompClass]::new(1)
$b = [CompClass]::new(1)
$a -eq $b # => False
$a -le $b # => True

Class EQClass : System.IEquatable[Object]
{
    [int] $Value
    EQClass([int] $v)
    {
        $this.Value = $v
    }
    [bool]Equals($that)
    {
        If (-Not($that -is [EQClass])) {
            Throw "Not comparable!!"
        }
        return $this.Value -eq $that.Value
    }
}

$c = [EQClass]::new(1)
$d = [EQClass]::new(1)
$c -eq $d # => True
```