Powershell, I have a question relating to a hashtable and how it sorts its contents for processing
I'm using a hashtable to change parts of PDF file names with unwanted sections. However, the portions of the names have similarities. Example: NameA_Fix.pdf, NameB_Fix1.pdf, NameC_Fix2.pdf. The goal is to remove the "_Fix", "_Fix1", and "_Fix2" using the simplest process possible. I know I can do individual searches for the whole section "_Fix2", "_Fix1", and then "_Fix" and this works, but that's a lot of repeat scripting. As for the hashtable, it appears that no matter how I list the values within, the result is always in simplest alphabetical order. "_Fix", "_Fix1", "_Fix2". After changing all names with "_Fix" first, the results will be "NameA.pdf", "NameB1.pdf", and "NameC2.pdf".
How do I work with a hashtable to make there the contents are processed in a certain order that I want?
I hope this makes sense with the details I've provided.
My trials have resulted in errors and the education that no sorting within the hashtable does any good. Due to my lack of advanced experience and education, this is why I'm reaching out for support.

isn't it easier to just remove _Fix and every numeric digit after it? i.e. .. | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '_Fix[0-9]*(?=\.pdf$) }

PS is written in Net Library and for custom comparison you use IComparable.  for same in PS see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090442/icomparable-interface-in-powershell

If you want preserved order, use an ordered dictionary instead: $names = [ordered]@{}

@SantiagoSquarzon, these were only template name examples. Not exact.

@MathiasR.Jessen. Thank you. I think this will do it.
